# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Four fair 6-sided dice are rolled. The sum of the numbers shown on the dice is 8. What is the probability that 2's were rolled on all four dice?

---

The answer should be 1/(# of ways 4 numbers sum to 8)
However, I can't find a way, other than listing all possibilities, to find the denominator.

Comment: So list, perhaps using shortcuts. For instance there are $4$ patterns of the type 5-1-1-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly brute force is nearly the best available option here.
\begin{align}
2+2+2+2 & & & 1 \text{ way} \\[6pt]
1+2+2+3 & & & 12\text{ ways} \\[6pt]
1+1+2+4 & & & 12\text{ ways} \\
1+1+3+3 & & & 6\text{ ways} \\[6pt]
1+1+1+5 & & & 4\text{ ways}
\end{align}

So you get $1/35$.

Answer (score 2):

I proved a relevant theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259869/rocks-and-squares-balls-and-sticks/1260278#1260278) ( for some reason this was closed )

Theorem 1: The number of distinct $n$-tuples of whole numbers whose components sum to a whole number $m$ is given by

$$ N^{(m)}_n \equiv \binom{m+n-1}{n-1}.$$

to apply this to your problem , you need to take into account that the theorem allows a minimum value of zero, but the dice show a minimum value of one. So you can just add one to each die so we are looking for the number of 4-tuples whose components sum to 4. I guess we are lucky that no element could possibly be greater than 6, so it will work for 6 sided dice.

The denominator is thus given by $$\binom 73 = 35 $$ which I have verified by enumeration.